# When we buy a domain online and build an entire company upon it, who guarantees that the domain name provider won't steal later on?

Tags: domain

When we buy a domain online and build an entire company upon it, who guarantees that the domain name provider won't steal later on?

Is there any difference among the providers? Like GoDaddy or others?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a case where this has happened?  Have you had this happen before, or are you just paranoid about it?

Answer (score 4):

These folks - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Corporation_for_Assigned_Names_and_Numbers (ICANN).